# Python Selenium Chromedriver File Download Not Working

Tags: python-2.7, csv, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium 3.4.3 in Python 2.7 to fill out a web form and download a generated CSV file. Using Chromedriver, the script goes all the way through, but the file in the downloads folder looks like this **10494_20170829000000.csv.crdownload**, and it's 0kb. This doesn't change after I close Chrome and the Python shell. I've tried changing the default download directory, but it always goes to C:/downloads and always has the crdownload extension.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)


def find_by_xpath(locator):
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator))
)

return element

class FormPage(object):

def fill_form(self, data):

    find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "h_UserName"]').send_keys(data['h_UserName'])
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "h_Password"]').send_keys(data['h_Password'])
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "h_go"]').click()
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "dldataformat"]').send_keys(data['dldataformat'])
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "startyear"]').send_keys(data['startyear'])
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "startmonth"]').send_keys(data['startmonth'])
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "startday"]').send_keys(data['startday'])
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "duration"]').click()
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "endyear"]').send_keys(data['endyear'])
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "endmonth"]').send_keys(data['endmonth'])
    find_by_xpath('//select[@name = "endday"]').send_keys(data['endday'])


    return self # makes it so you can call .submit() after calling this function

def submit(self):
    find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "cmd"]').click()

data = {
'h_UserName':'',
'h_Password':'',
'dldataformat': '0',
'startyear': '2017',
'startmonth': '8',
'startday': '29',
'endyear': '2017',
'endmonth': '8',
'endday': '30'
}

FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()
driver.quit() # closes the webbrowser
```

Comment: How can you download anything without clicking on some `WebElements`? Where is the `click()` method invoked? The `10494_20170829000000.csv.crdownload` you are seeing maybe a result of previous execution.

Comment: how about putting `time.sleep(30)` after `driver.get(url)`

Comment: Post complete script

Comment: Tried time.sleep, didn't help. Posted most of the script. I can't share the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The browser was closing before the file download was finished, so I added a time.sleep(10) before driver.quit().